# creating loops for my little game

Tags: python

I am making a simple game with Python. And I'm having a hard time making my game loops. Can someone help me complete my little game.

```
import random
print ('Welcome to the Lottery')
dollar = 100
print 'Your money: $' + str(dollar)
print 'Enter your bet:'
bet= raw_input('(ex.$100)')

remaining = dollar - int(bet)
if bet <= dollar:
    print 'Your money: $' + str(remaining)
    print 'Bet:$' + bet
elif bet > dollar:
    print 'You don\'t have enough money'
    raw_input('(ex.$100)')
    while bet > dollar:
        print 'You don\'t have enough money'
        raw_input('(ex.$100)')
else:
    print 'You don\'t have any bets.'

raw_input('Enter you number (1-999):')
raw_input('Play? (yes or no)')
for i in range(1):
        (random.randint(1,999))
        print(random.randint(1,999))
```

Comment: Just an FYI that "please finish my work" is not a question.  That said, you're lacking a loop that encapsulates the entirety of game play.  Enclose the entire play section in a while true loop and then please re-word your question to specific programming and code related errors.  Happy to help but its all about code!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `while` as a loop.

For example, if you wanted to keep repeating your program until the user types a specific word (ex. "exit"):

```
import random
print ('Welcome to the Lottery')
dollar = 100
bet = ""
while not bet == "exit":
    print 'Your money: $' + str(dollar)
    print 'Enter your bet:'
    bet= raw_input('(ex.$100)')

    remaining = dollar - int(bet)
    if bet <= dollar:
        print 'Your money: $' + str(remaining)
        print 'Bet:$' + bet
    elif bet > 0:
        print 'You don\'t have enough money'
    else:
        print 'You don\'t have any bets.'


    for i in range(1):
            (random.randint(1,999))
            #return(random.randint(1,999))
print("Goodbye!") # Prints 'Goodbye!' after the user types 'exit'.
```

Alternatively, you can use `while True` for an infinite loop.

Here's some info and examples: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm